# Configure web reference VS 2010 for different environments

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, configuration

I have a legacy project, which has several web references and I would like to configure different endpoints depending on the environment (local, dev, staging, production).

I have read this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12317/How-to-make-your-Web-Reference-proxy-URL-dynamic), but VS is using `Settings.settings` and applicationSettings instead of `appSettings`, so instead of using

```
this.Url = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["foo_Api"]
```

is using `this.Url = global::foo.Properties.Settings.Default.foo_Api;`

My app.config look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="foo.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <applicationSettings>
        <foo.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="foo_Api" serializeAs="String">
                <value>http://myserver/server/Api.asmx</value>
            </setting>
        </foo.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

I have read about configuring with `machine.config`, but that doesn't work in my case as there are different environments in the same machine. Changing the Url property at runtime isn't the best solution either as I would need to change all the usages of the web reference.

Ideally I would like to use `appSettings` so I can put a local.config to override the values of the endpoint, but if there is a simple way of overriding the values of `applicationSettings` is fine too.

**EDIT**

This a dll project. Don't know if this may affect somehow.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question - what's the problem with `Settings.settings` class? It's just upgraded visually supported app config with all its benefits. What's the problem with changing it to old app config style?

Comment: The problem is that it uses `applicationSettings` and I havent't been able to use something like, `<applicationSettings file=local.config`> with it as it is used with appSettings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it can help anyone: finally after some research the best solution I found is adding a Visual Studio configuration profile and a `Web.config` transformation for each environment. Then I just simply add to `Web.config` the local web reference endpoint and a transformation in each `Web.{environment}.config` that replace the endpoint value.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can include external config files to your applicationSettings section, thus allowing you to tune config for different environment:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <foo.Properties.Settings configSource="ConfigFolder\local.config">
    </foo.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

local.config:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <foo.Properties.Settings configSource="local.config">
        <setting name="foo_Api" serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://myserver/server/Api.asmx</value>
        </setting>
    </foo.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings
```

Comment: That's a nice solution but now I am having another problem: configSource seems to be configured properly as a change on `Settings.settings` updates `local.config`, but when it comes to running the application, it just simply ignores whatever is the value in `local.config`. If the `GeneratedDefaultValueInCode` is `True` it uses the value in `Settings.settings`, otherwise the value is `null`.

Comment: What is `GeneratedDefaultValueInCode`?

Comment: It is a property of the web reference in `Settings.settings`. If true the default value is added to the code.

Comment: All the configuration values are actually stored in app.config and not in Settings.settings. You should look at your app.config file and local.config file. BTW when you debug your app in VS, you should look at vshost.exe.config file.

Comment: in the end the problem of the null endpoint has been fixed by adding the applicationSettings on the Web.config from the Web app project. It seems that the app.config from the dll project is useless.